# Parallelization of true dependencies

Tags: c, loops, parallel-processing, dependencies, openmp

is it worth to parallelize true dependency loops? What could be the pros and cons? How much speedup can we get on average?

For example:

```
    int sum = 0;
    for(i=0;i<2000-1;i++){
            for(j=0;j<2000;j++) {
                curr[i][j] = some_value_here;
                sum += curr[i][j];
            }
    }
```

How should I approach to this loop? there is a obvious RAW dependency, should I parallelize it? If so, how should I?

Comment: The answer to this question lies in my answer to your other question.

Comment: Which one, lol!

Comment: What do you mean by “true” dependency? There is an obvious read-after-write dependency; `sum` is written in each iteration and read in the next. How much speed-up can be gotten cannot be stated without knowing hardware characteristics. The code as written does a chain of 3,998,000 additions, but it the dependency depth could be reduced to ceil(log[2](3,998,000−1)) = 22, so the potential speedup for the addition in isolation is more than 181,727 if you have the hardware for it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, this is actually a simple reduction problem and the speedup is roughly equal to the number of execution units.

Comment: @HristoIliev: As I wrote, it depends on the hardware. The question asks for how much speedup we can get on average, and that is not a sensible question in absence of hardware specifications.

Answer (score 2):

`sum` acts as a simple accumulator and this whole operation is a parallel reduction. The proper solution is to have each thread accumulate its own private sum and then add all private sums together at the end. OpenMP provides the `reduction` clause that does exactly that:

```
int sum = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) reduction(+:sum)
for(i=0;i<2000-1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<2000;j++) {
            curr[i][j] = some_value_here;
            sum += curr[i][j];
        }
}
```

`reduction(+:sum)` tells the compiler to create private copies of `sum` and then apply the `+` operator to reduce those private copies to a single value that is then added to the value `sum` had before the region. The code is roughly equivalent to:

```
int sum = 0;
#pragma omp parallel
{
   int localsum = 0;
   #pragma omp for collapse(2)
   for(i=0;i<2000-1;i++) {
      for(j=0;j<2000;j++) {
         curr[i][j] = some_value_here;
         localsum += curr[i][j];
      }
   }
   #pragma omp atomic
   sum += localsum;
}
```

The potential speedup here is equal to the number of execution units provided that you have one thread per execution unit and that there aren't that many threads so that the synchronous summation at the end of the parallel region takes negligible time.

Comment: I am using 16 and 32 threads to test, do you think that your way with atomic operation is a good choice?

Comment: I am **not** saying to use `atomic` - it is just for illustration of what OpenMP does for you when you apply the `reduction` clause.